# How to bind to inkstrokes from the UWP InkCanvas hosted by WPF?

Tags: wpf, uwp, windows-runtime

I am truly reaching here :) (I am a complete newbie to UWP/WinRt)

I am hosting a custom WinRT InkCanvas in a WPF Window. I am completely new to WinRt, so when it comes to loading or saving the inkstroke data, I am lost. The problem is getting/setting
the InkStrokes when they are burried within the InkContainer. I would like to use XAML binding from the WPF window to a backend F# module. (Elmish.wpf).

I currently do have both Elmish.wpf and the WinRT Inkcanvas working in the same application.
(Elmish.wpf runs fine with the new application interface required to host WinRT/UWP controls).

ANY HELP OR GUIDANCE WOULD BE MOST APPRECIATED!

So, not knowing how to get the inkstrokes, this is what I have so far:

**My WPF container -- ProgressNoteWindow**
Note the use of WindowsXamlHost. Somehow, I need the button go gain access to the inkstrokes contained in the InkContainer of Inkcanvas being hosted by the WindowsXamlHost!

```
<Window x:Class="Stargate.XI.Client.Views.ProgressNoteWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:xaml="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stargate.XI.Client.Views"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ProgressNoteWindow" d:DesignHeight="1200" d:DesignWidth="1200">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       

        <xaml:WindowsXamlHost x:Name="MyInkControl" Grid.Row="1" InitialTypeName="Loader2.MyUserControl2" ChildChanged="WindowsXamlHost_ChildChanged" />


        <Button Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding InkStrokes, ElementName=MyInkControl}" Content = "Save"/>
       

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**My attached property --InkCanvasBinder**

```
public static class InkCanvasBinder
    {
        public static InkStrokeContainer GetInkStrokes(DependencyObject obj) =>
            obj.GetValue(InkStrokesProperty) as InkStrokeContainer;

        public static void SetInkStrokes(DependencyObject obj, InkStrokeContainer value) =>
            obj.SetValue(InkStrokesProperty, value);

        public static DependencyProperty InkStrokesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "InkStrokes", typeof(InkStrokeContainer), typeof(InkCanvasBinder),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, InkStrokesProperty_PropertyChanged));

        private static void InkStrokesProperty_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var inkCanvas = d as InkCanvas;
            if (inkCanvas != null) inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer = e.NewValue as InkStrokeContainer;
        }
    }
```

**MyUserControl (in a UWP project):**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Loader2.MyUserControl2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Loader2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="1200"
    d:DesignWidth="1200">

    <Grid Background="LightCoral">
        <InkCanvas  x:Name="TheInkCanvas" Loaded="InkCanvas_OnLoaded" local:InkCanvasBinder.InkStrokes = "{x:Bind MyInkStrokeContainer}"/>

        <!-- Ensure the InkToolbar is declared after the InkCanvas. If not, the InkCanvas overlay renders the InkToolbar inaccessible., Mode=OneWay-->
        <InkToolbar x:Name="myInkToolbar" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind TheInkCanvas}" Width="300" Height="50" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
    
</UserControl>
```

**MyUserControl - code-behind (in a UWP project)**

```
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Input.Inking;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

// The User Control item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace Loader2
{
    public sealed partial class MyUserControl2 : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl2()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InkCanvas_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TheInkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;
        }


        public InkStrokeContainer MyInkStrokeContainer
        {
            get { return (InkStrokeContainer)GetValue(MyInkStrokeContainerProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyInkStrokeContainerProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyInkStrokeContainer.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyInkStrokeContainerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyInkStrokeContainer", typeof(InkStrokeContainer), typeof(MyUserControl2), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you have good reason to not use the WPF InkCanvas?

Comment: @Clemens I am under the belief that the inkanalyzer in UWP is superior to that in WPF. If that is not the case, please tell me now!

Comment: I doubt that an inkstrokecontainer is bindable. I suggest you listen to events or use the getstrokes method to get your strokes. Once you have a tr

Comment: Stroke  you can get drawing points and build a geometry or something that wpf can work with.

Comment: @Andy ultimately I need the InkAnalyzer with the best handwriting recognition. Does UWP and wpf both use the same api’s for handwriting recognition? I find going between wpf and uwp a painful experience. Thanks.

Comment: I've not tried uwp ink so no idea.  Wpf ink doesn't recognise handwriting, it smooths jiggly parts of a stroke.

Comment: @Clemens Can I infer from your question that staying inside wpf would be better then jumping into xaml islands? (It would sure be a whole lot easier!)

Comment: I can't tell what would be "better", that depends on your requirements. Far easier for sure.